# Squid's URL modification/rewrite

Tags: url, url-rewriting, squid

I need to modify some special URLs which are passed over Squid, for example: i access the address www.google.com.vn through out my Squid. I want to modify Squid source code at some where to replace www.google.com.vn into www.google.com. So every requests to www.google.com.vn will become requests to www.google.com

Please help ASPS

Answer (score 3):

First of all, squid rewriting and redirecting depends on a third party helper.
The best part is that you can write this helper in ***any programming language***.

use the `url_rewrite_program` directive in squid.conf
and add to it the path to your custom made script.
Your script will receive content with the following:

`URL  client_ip "/" fqdn  user  method [ kvpairs]\n`

Obviously you need the `URL` part,so figure a way to get the url part and return the website you want the client to be directed to.

Hope that help in any way...

Example rewrite programm (C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// a replace function :)
bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
    return false;
str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
return true;
}


int main()
{
     while(1)
     {
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        replace(input, "www.google.vn", "www.google.com");
        cout << input << endl;
     }

}
```