# What is the easiest way to set up a flexible HTTP proxy on Windows

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

I'm looking for a HTTP proxy on Windows, with which can easily apply some simple rules/filters onto.

For example, I can let the traffic of `http://sitea.com/images.*` all goes with  `http://localhost/images.*`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Squid on Windows. I think this article explains a url_rewrite_program that can be called to do what you need:
[Squid's URL modification/rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934102/squids-url-modification-rewrite)

Good luck!